# Is there a way to move mouse coordinates to the title of the JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

Got `method` `paint()` to draw mouse coordinates in `JFrame` in coordinates `x=20, y=20`. Is there a way to move rendering mouse coordinates to the `title` of the `JFrame`? Try to use `jFrame.setTitle()` but it want `String` as parametr.

```
 jFrame.setTitle(g.drawString("Coordinates x:" + xCord + " y" + yCord, 20, 20)) not work.
```

Here is my code:

```
 private static void paint() {
        JComponent jComponent = new JComponent() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Font font = new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 20);
                g.setFont(font);
                g.drawString("Coordinates x:" + xCord + " y" + yCord, 20, 20);

            }
        };

        jFrame.add(jComponent);
        jFrame.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseMoved(e);
                xCord = e.getX();
                yCord = e.getY();
                jComponent.repaint();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example of a GUI that updates the title of the JFrame.

[image: Coordinates GUI]

I just updated the title `String` with the coordinates from the `mouseMoved` method of the `MouseMOtionListener`.

Here's the runnable, contained, example.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MouseCoordinatesTitle implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MouseCoordinatesTitle());
    }
    
    private JFrame frame;
    
    private String title;
    
    public MouseCoordinatesTitle() {
        this.title = "Coordinates: ";
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel());
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
        panel.addMouseMotionListener(new PositionListener());
        return panel;
    }
    
    public void updateJFrameTitle(Point point) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(title);
        builder.append("X: ");
        builder.append(point.x);
        builder.append(", Y: ");
        builder.append(point.y);
        frame.setTitle(builder.toString());
    }
    
    public class PositionListener implements MouseMotionListener {

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
            Point point = event.getPoint();
            updateJFrameTitle(point);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
        
        }

    }

}
```